# How do terraform providers implement resource lifecycle (resource's STOPPED status)?

Tags: terraform

Context: I'm developing a terraform provider.

HashiCorp's [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-delete) describes how to manage a resource that can be in 2 states pretty much: `CREATED` and `DELETED` (or such that `GET resources/{resource_id}` returns `404`). It's easy to support `CREATING` (that means creation is in progress) state as well by adding a retries / wait in `resourceCreate()` method.

What about implementing a support for more advanced states like `STOPPED`? Is it a thing to add a computed `status` attribute or something that can be either `CREATED` or `STOPPED` and set it to `CREATED` in terraform configuration file (or make this attribute computed) and make `status` attribute updateable?

Comment: `CREATED` and `STOPPED` would both return a successful `Read`, and therefore be equivalent in the schema. If you wanted to differentiate between the two, then I think that would require an update to the provider sdk.

Comment: > require an update to the provider sdk.
basically adding `status` attribute?

Comment: It would need to expand the potential information one could extract from `Read`.